# Would there be no electrostatic repulsion if you make two protons hit head on w.r.t their spin (i.e. opposite angular momentum)?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, protons

Basically the title. If you have two protons the have a strong electrostatic repulsion. However their spin produces a magnetic field and if you orient them like in the picture there would be magnetic attraction. If you would orient them perfectly, could you cancel the electrostatic repulsion eventually? How far can you make them reduce it?

[image]

More generally how does the net force change w.r.t. changing angle like this:
[image]

Comment: If you go to the trouble to put units and calculate , you would find that the magnetic attraction is very very much smaller than the electric repulsion. Experimental fact: two protons do not bind into a nucleus.

Comment: @annav it seems experimental evidence of ${}^2\text{He}$ does exist which mean even though it's highly unstable one can have two protons form a nucleus.

Comment: @Triatticus  do you have a link for this?

Comment: [Spin isomers of hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen)